# Split value as key and value using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to extract data in key and value format.. I have stuck how to split this html into key and value using Jsoup.please guide me

```
 <div class="text">
        Flamingnet Student Book Reviewer  LGen080812
        <br/>
             Aine (pronounced Ah-nee) has always thought of herself as a normal teenager in Depression-Era Alabama. With her blind brother Spenser, she lives in her grandmother's farmhouse, playing in the woods, reading books, and going to school--but never going outside the farmhouse other than school. But on the one day that their grandmother lets them go to town, Aine and Spenser return only to find that the person they call grandmother isn't actually their grandmother at all, and that she's been murdered. Not to mention that they've actually been living in a book all along. Soon Aine and Spenser are on the run from their grandma's killer, Biblos, with the legendary Gilgamesh. The two siblings hop from novel to novel as they embark on a quest to find three objects to save their world.
        <p>There were a number of things that hindered me from enjoying The Toadhouse Trilogy: Book One. First of all, the narrative was told in the present tense and in the third person. This is not automatically a bad thing for a book, but the style of the prose constructed really awkward sentences at times, eg. "The size of her failure feels epic." The premise for the book felt incredibly uninspired at times; I truly had a lot of trouble getting into and finishing the book. We also never find out what book Aine and Spenser were living in. Speaking of Aine and Spenser, I thought that their characters could be developed a bit better. However, Jess Lourey did do a wonderful job creating Gilgameshs character and using her vivid imagery. The Toadhouse Trilogy: Book One is not a bad book, but I wouldnt recommend it to my friends. </p>
        <p/>
        <p>Reviewer Age:13</p>
    </div>
```

**Expected output:**

> "id":"LGen080812" "text":"Aine (pronounced Ah-nee) has always thought
>   of herself as a normal teenager in Depression-Era Alabama. With her
>   blind brother Spenser, she lives in her grandmother's farmhouse,
>   playing in the woods, reading books, and going to school--but never
>   going outside the farmhouse other than school. But on the one day that
>   their grandmother lets them go to town, Aine and Spenser return only
>   to find that the person they call grandmother isn't actually their
>   grandmother at all, and that she's been murdered. Not to mention that
>   they've actually been living in a book all along. Soon Aine and
>   Spenser are on the run from their grandma's killer, Biblos, with the
>   legendary Gilgamesh. The two siblings hop from novel to novel as they
>   embark on a quest to find three objects to save their world. There
>   were a number of things that hindered me from enjoying The Toadhouse
>   Trilogy: Book One. First of all, the narrative was told in the present
>   tense and in the third person. This is not automatically a bad thing
>   for a book, but the style of the prose constructed really awkward
>   sentences at times, eg. "The size of her failure feels epic." The
>   premise for the book felt incredibly uninspired at times; I truly had
>   a lot of trouble getting into and finishing the book. We also never
>   find out what book Aine and Spenser were living in. Speaking of Aine
>   and Spenser, I thought that their characters could be developed a bit
>   better. However, Jess Lourey did do a wonderful job creating
>   Gilgameshs character and using her vivid imagery. The Toadhouse
>   Trilogy: Book One is not a bad book, but I wouldnt recommend it to my
>   friends." "rating":"13"

my code:

```
String html = response.body();
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
String review = document.select("div[class=text]").last().text();
System.out.println(review);
```

Comment: `I have stuck...` it means that you have some (even not working code). Can we see it?

Comment: the lack of structure  of that document makes this difficult are you able to restructure the html document ?

Comment: @Pshemo:i have converted html values into string . I do no how to split like that..please help me.. here is my code..                   String html = response.body();
  Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
  String review = document.select("div[class=text]").last().text();
  System.out.println(review);

Comment: @Giridharan Don't post code in comment. It is unreadable. Instead use [[edit]] option and place it your question.

Comment: Does this is guaranteed to have at start `Flamingnet Student Book Reviewer  [id]`, at end `Reviewer Age:[rating]`? Also should entire text between these elements be placed in `text` element?

Comment: @Pshemo: see this link i need to extract reviewer comment..http://flamingnet.com/bookreviews/newreviews/newbookreview.cfm?title=Truesight

Answer (score 0):

It seems that page from your comment uses JavaScript to dynamically fill its content and Jsoup can't execute JavaScript. But from your code example it seems that you are able to get generated content of this site with

```
String html = response.body();
```

so I will focus on that part. If you are sure that text in `review` will always be in form

```
Flamingnet Student Book Reviewer [id] [long text] Reviewer Age:[rating]
```

then you can use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). You can try with this code:

```
String html = response.body();
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
String review = document.select("div[class=text]").last().text();

Pattern p = Pattern
        .compile(
                "Flamingnet Student Book Reviewer\\s+(?<id>\\w+)\\s+(?<text>.+)\\s+Reviewer Age:(?<rating>\\d+)",
                Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(review);
if (m.matches()){
    System.out.println("id = "+m.group("id"));
    System.out.println("text = "+m.group("text"));
    System.out.println("rating = "+m.group("rating"));
}else{
    System.out.println("Pattern doesn't match. Incorrect data.");
}
```

You should see something similar to

```
id = LGen080812
text = Aine (pronounced Ah-nee) has always thought of herself as a normal teenager in Depression-Era Alabama. With her blind brother Spenser, she lives in her grandmother's farmhouse, playing in the woods, reading books, and going to school--but never going outside the farmhouse other than school. But on the one day that their grandmother lets them go to town, Aine and Spenser return only to find that the person they call grandmother isn't actually their grandmother at all, and that she's been murdered. Not to mention that they've actually been living in a book all along. Soon Aine and Spenser are on the run from their grandma's killer, Biblos, with the legendary Gilgamesh. The two siblings hop from novel to novel as they embark on a quest to find three objects to save their world. There were a number of things that hindered me from enjoying The Toadhouse Trilogy: Book One. First of all, the narrative was told in the present tense and in the third person. This is not automatically a bad thing for a book, but the style of the prose constructed really awkward sentences at times, eg. "The size of her failure feels epic." The premise for the book felt incredibly uninspired at times; I truly had a lot of trouble getting into and finishing the book. We also never find out what book Aine and Spenser were living in. Speaking of Aine and Spenser, I thought that their characters could be developed a bit better. However, Jess Lourey did do a wonderful job creating Gilgameshs character and using her vivid imagery. The Toadhouse Trilogy: Book One is not a bad book, but I wouldnt recommend it to my friends.
rating = 13
```

Now you can use these values to create your output.

Comment: what we need to parse for review